# JavaFX ListView rounded corners using CSS

Tags: css, listview, javafx

I want to have rounded corners on my ListView. The CSS I currently have rounds the corners until I add a new string to the ListView, then the corners are no longer round. I am using an ObservableList to store my strings and have the ListView set to the ObservableList.

I've also checked the [JavaFX CSS](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#listview) reference but couldn't find anything useful to my issue.

[No text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PbXD.jpg)
[After text is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccVq2.jpg)

My current css

```css
.list-view {
    -fx-background-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: The problem is with `list-cell` that is located above the background of `list-view`. You can check it by setting a property `-fx-background-color: transparent` to `list-cell`. I don't think this problem can be solved without tricks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example the default styling of list cell is overlapping the round background of the list view. You can add some padding to the list view so there isn't any overlapping. You can have round borders for the items of the list view as well.

**FXML:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>


<HBox spacing="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <ListView fx:id="listView1" style="-fx-background-radius: 20;">
         <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
               <String fx:value="Item 1" />
               <String fx:value="Item 2" />
               <String fx:value="Item 3" />
            </FXCollections>
         </items>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
         </padding>
      </ListView>
      <ListView fx:id="listView" stylesheets="@styling.css">
         <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
               <String fx:value="Item 1" />
               <String fx:value="Item 2" />
               <String fx:value="Item 3" />
            </FXCollections>
         </items>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="7.0" left="7.0" right="7.0" top="7.0" />
         </padding>
      </ListView>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
   </padding>
</HBox>
```

**styling.css** (for second list view):

```
.list-view {
    -fx-background-radius: 20;
}

.list-cell, .list-cell::focused {
    -fx-border-radius: 20;
}
```

**Preview:**

[image]